# Cannot decrypt a file which was encrypted using Talend tFileArchive component

Tags: encryption, talend

I encrypted a file using tFileArchive component in Talend 5.6.

Configs are:
    Encoding: UTF-8
    Encrypt method AES256bit

And I'm trying to decrypt it using another way, I used

```
openssl enc -d -aes256 -in testEncrypt.csv -out tmp/dectestEnd.csv
```

in linux but it says: `bad magic number`

What am I doing wrong here.

**Update**

I'm using Talend 5.6
And below is a the config of the job. The file testEncrypt.csv can be successfully decrypt using tFileUnarchive component.

[image: Config of tFileArchive]

Comment: Why is your encrypted archive called testEncrypt.csv ? I would expect a zip file instead

Comment: @iMezouar I wanted file content to be encrypted and file type should be csv type. So in the Talend component I’ve give that as a csv file

Comment: If I understand correctly, testEncrypt.csv is the input file you give to tFileArchive, but in the end you would get an encrypted archive right ? Then the encrypted archive should be the argument to openssl decrypt command

Comment: @iMezouar No. My input file to tFileArchive is test.csv and it creates testEncrypt.csv, which is the content encrypted csv file. (Sorry for the unclear point). Using tFileUnarchive Talend component I can successfully decrypt the generated (testEncrypt.csv) csv file back using the same password. But I want to verify this encrypted file can be decrypt using some other method (except Talend).

Comment: I did some research and Talend documentation states that the encrypted file can only be decompressed using only tFileUnarchive and not a common archiver https://help.talend.com/reader/iYcvdknuprDzYycT3WRU8w/~V42EBQClKxKQghNvzHF1g I'll look some more into this and post my findings

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: @James this is Talend related, which is a valid tag in SO. How is this off topic ?

Comment: Tags are irrelevant. Read the link in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you were looking at it the wrong way.
`tFileArchive` creates an archive of one or more files and can optionally password-protect it. So in your example you would get a zip file which is password protected using AES256 encryption, which contains your test.csv file.
Here's the example I used to test this (create an archive containing one file json.txt, protected using the password "password") :

[image]

Now the resulting `archive.zip` is a valid archive, only it's password-protected. So passing it to `openssl` results in an error `bad magic number` because it's not an encrypted file per se.
In order to decompress it, I used `7za` command to verify it (which you can install using  `sudo apt install p7zip-full`) :

```
7za l -slt archive.zip
```

Output:

```
7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18  
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)  

Listing archive: archive.zip                                          

--                                                                    
Path = archive.zip                                                    
Type = zip                                                            
Physical Size = 281                                                   

----------                                                            
Path = json.txt                                                       
Folder = -                                                            
Size = 171                                                            
Packed Size = 129                                                     
Modified = 2018-01-12 09:25:04                                        
Created =                                                             
Accessed =                                                            
Attributes = .....                                                    
Encrypted = +                                                         
Comment =                                                             
CRC =                                                                 
Method = AES-256 Deflate                                              
Host OS = FAT                                                         
Version = 20
```

You can see the encryption method in `Method = AES-256 Deflate`.
Then you can decompress it using this command :

```
7za e -mem=AES256 archive.zip -ppassword
```

Output:

```
7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)

Processing archive: archive.zip

Extracting  json.txt

Everything is Ok

Size:       171
Compressed: 281
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm using Talend 5.6 and in that I can't see the archive format option. Added more information on the job I tried.

Comment: Yes there are slight differences, but my answer is still valid. The main takeaway is, regardless of the the file extension, the result is an archive file (as I detailed in my answer). So your file testEncrypt.csv is a zip file, and not an encrypted file, that's why openssl doesn't accept it. If your requirement is to just encrypt the file and not create an archive out of it, you should look at tSystem component, and call openssl encrypt command.